# How do you grant access to a container using an Access Policy?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of Access Policies at the moment, or at least how you can use them programmatically. If I create a Storage Access policy with certain permissions, how can I then programmatically use that access policy? I can create it like this (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-stored-access-policy-define-dotnet?tabs=dotnet)):

```
var signedIdentifiers = new List<BlobSignedIdentifier>
{
    new BlobSignedIdentifier
    {
        Id = "SomeIdentifier",
        AccessPolicy = new BlobAccessPolicy
        {
            StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
            Permissions = "w"
        }
    }
};

await containerClient.SetAccessPolicyAsync(permissions: signedIdentifiers);
```

So I've create the access policy, so how can I now create access to that container using that access policy? Do I need to generate a SAS somehow? If so, how will that SAS make sure it uses the permissions from that access policy? The fact it's a list suggests that more than one policy can be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I've create the access policy, so how can I now create access to
> that container using that access policy? Do I need to generate a SAS
> somehow?

That is correct. You will need to generate a SAS Token using this access policy. If you are generating a SAS Token on the blob container, you will use [`GenerateSasUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.generatesasuri?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobcontainerclient-generatesasuri(azure-storage-sas-blobsasbuilder)) method and specify the access policy id (signed identifier) as [`BlobSasBuilder.Identifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.blobsasbuilder.identifier?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-sas-blobsasbuilder-identifier).

> If so, how will that SAS make sure it uses the permissions from that
> access policy?

When you create a SAS URL that makes use of an access policy, you will notice that access policy id in your SAS URL in `si` query parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specifying-the-signed-identifier). That would tell Azure Storage to make use of the signed access policy for SAS Token verification.

> The fact it's a list suggests that more than one policy can be
> created.

That is correct. A blob container can have a maximum of 5 access policies. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy.